# Do the ReSharper Unit test runner not support WinRT MSTest framework ?

Tags: windows-runtime, resharper, mstest

Scenario: I have Visual Studio 2012, ReSharper 7.0.1, and am creating a WinRT (Metro) app.

I create a new unit test project, using the template "Unit Test Project (Windows Store App)"; and I create this test:

```
[TestClass]
public class FirstTest
{
    [TestMethod]
    public void DummyTest()
    {
        Assert.AreEqual(1,1);
    }
}
```

This runs nicely in the built in test runner, but trying to run it with R#, I get a messagebox with the message:

```
 No tests found in file.
```

Does ReSharper not support this scenario ? Or am I missing something completely  obvious ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I got a reply for this on Twitter from one of the R# devs: This is not supported in R# 7.0.1.

They're working on it - The latest EAP build supports MSTest on WinRT. (Or at least, Build #5, 08 Oct 2012, works for me). Problem solved.